# Couldn't find suitable architecture for linking arm64 in Mach-O file Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension

Tags: xcode, onesignal, arm64, mach-o

When archiving the project, I'm getting the below error after tap on distributing in Xcode

couldn't find suitable architecture for linking arm64 in Mach-O file /var/folders/36/x3lk24wj2333jtl767bbzgc80000gn/T/ipatool20210917-65819-szkdq8/universal-MachOs/Payload/Runner.app/PlugIns/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension.appex/OneSignalNotificationServiceExtension

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue in Xcode
In my case architecture arm64 was excluded

Go Build settings > excluded architecture Section > click and remove exculded architecture